# Getting an error while installing drupal 7 using xampp

Tags: ajax, database, installation

Getting an error while installing drupal 7 using xampp

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path:
>   http://localhost/tes/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do
>   StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30
>   seconds exceeded in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\tes\includes\database\database.inc
>   on line 2171

I also tried reinstalling xampp but still didnt work out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare & update these values in `php.ini`.

> max_execution_time = 300
>
> max_input_time = 180
>
> max_input_nesting_level = 300
>
> memory_limit = 512M

**Note** : After these changes, restart the server.

Comment: nope...still not working..!!!

Comment: @ReckeR Have you restarted the server after changes?

Comment: okay..the error gone...installed successfully...but I can't login...it doesn't even give any error...it just says access denied

Comment: actually it just worked out with firefox but still not working with damn chrome...!!!

Comment: once try to clear browser cache.

Comment: I cleaned all the cache from everywhere but still didn't work.. Nway I'm not gonna bother any more... Thanks a lot man!

Comment: You welcome @ReckeR